# Divs showing and then hiding on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

i am using jquery on an asp.net page with master page and my purpose is to hide divs.
So i use

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

Now the Dilemma is that as the button is clicked on the page the divs show for a second and then hide.There seems a flicker before the div hides.
Can someone explain me how to fix that.
Can we adjust the css.
i've put the hide code before the css.
thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code for the button, and how you're hooking it up to that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
$('#myDiv').css('display','none');
```

There is an difference between `hide` and `display:none`.

If you choose `hide` then the selected element will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), **except** that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache **so that display can later be restored to its initial value**. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Comment: Uhm, this is exactly what `hide()` does, one would thing the issue is the DOM ready wait, not the method applying the styles ?

Comment: They are same that I know but there is light different between them acc to display vise.See my edit once.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate what you mean by "I have put the hide code before the css". You can do what you are trying to do in simply by doing something like below

```
<div id="myDiv">div1</div>
<button id="button1" >button</button>
<script>
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```